# Error inflating class fragment second time around

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am brand new to android app development

I have the following code

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
```

Later on i have the following

```
fragment = homeFragment;
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

The home fragment has the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp" 
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"               
    android:gravity="top"   
    android:background="#D3D3D3" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="128dp"       
        android:paddingLeft="0dp" 
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"           
        android:gravity="top"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_right"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_out_left">
    </ViewFlipper>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"         
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center" />

     <!-- ***** THIS IS WHAT IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM ***** -->             
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/the_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="129dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The first time the HomeFragment works perfectly

The second time I get "Error inflating class fragment"

I have looked at many different things but nothing that applies to my situation

Any help would be greatly appreciated

### LOGCAT

10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701): Process: com.tobesafe.tobesafe, PID: 3701
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class fragment
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at com.tobesafe.tobesafe.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:80)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #48: Duplicate id 0x7f08005f, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4791)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
10-28 12:49:10.712: E/AndroidRuntime(3701):     ... 19 more

Comment: A stack trace would be good. Show us your Logcat.

Comment: How are you closing it the first time?

Comment: What do you mean by manually?

Comment: I don't close it. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I just changed the comment to an answer for a detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

That layout is inflated in the HomeFragment or HomeActivity? if that is inflated in a fragment that is the problem. You can't inflate a fragment in a layout inside a fragment, you have to do that manually. Here is a reference for it: [Nested Fragments](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment supportMapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_TAG_MAPFRAGMENT);
        if (supportMapfragment == null) {
            supportMapfragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_fragment, supportMapfragment).commit();
        }
        return v;
    }
```

make sure to use [getChildFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) instead of normal [getFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager())

Answer (score 0):

First,
I don't think it's logical to add a Fragment with another Fragment in it already.
Second I don't understand why you guys be like:

```
FragmentManager fragMan;
fragMan.beginTransaction().replace(blah blah blah. . . );
```

I don't think that's a good practice. I believe it's better doing all that with a FragmentTransaction object:

```
FragmentTransaction ft;
ft = (FragmentTransaction) getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(blah blah blah. . . . );
ft.commit();
```

Maybe you guys know something I don't.
Regards.